# Custom name for Parameterized tests

Tags: java, junit, parameterized

I have a `Parameterized` test to which I pass an object as a parameter. I know I can give a custom name with `@Parameters(name="{2}")`, but the default `toString()` is called and it's not very clear. I would like to have a method which would return a string depending on the object attributes. For now I added another parameter for this. Is there a way to add a method for this ?

Comment: would overriding the `toString` method work?

Comment: Pass in an extra parameter containing the name you want to display?

Comment: @ValentinCarnu no I can't change it.

Comment: @AndyTurner Yes that's what I'm doing right now but I wonder if there is a better way to do it

Comment: You could wrap the parameter in a custom class and override toString there.

Answer (score 0):

Passing an extra parameter as test case name is the right way.